# Remove the suffix on Id of the object through APEX CLASS

Tags: apex, visualforce

How could I remove the suffix of Id to make it 15 char instead of 18 through APEX Class.

Example:

```
CustomObject obj = new CustomObject();

obj.Subject = 'Subject here';

insert obj;

String ObjId = obj.id(This give me 18 character Id, I only want 15 character ID)
```

Comment: All you need to do is drop the last characters. There's plenty of [String methods](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_methods_system_string.htm) that would allow you to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no "suffix" to remove. The only difference between an 18 digit character Id and a 15 digit character Id is that the latter is case sensitive while the former is not. Utilities, such as the Chrome extension already exist for the purpose of converting between the two. The only time one needs a 15 digit character Id is when exporting data to an outside program such as Excel. When working internally, the data needs to be in 18 digit character form.

Comment: e.g. on the URL params ID is 18 character then I use {!$CurrentPage.parameters.id} it give me only 15 character?

Comment: Will an 18 character Id not work for you for some reason? When you insert an object, SF will save it with an 18 character Id.